# Get content from Json file inside the project

Tags: c#, json, file, windows-phone-8, readfile

I'm trying to get content from file which is located in my project. But all the time I got `"Could not find a part of the path "`

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"/Resources/Database/questionsTEST.json"))
```

My JSON file is located in `Resources/Database/questionsTEST.json`.

I try also with `test.txt` located in main project, but still nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application is executing from a child directory of the project corresponding to your current build settings, for example 'YourProject\bin\Debug'.  You say the file is part of your project, so it lives here 'YourProject\test.txt', however your code is looking for 'YourProject\bin\Debug\test.txt'.

You will need to make the file test.txt part of the project output.  Within the project, right click on test.txt and change the output type to Content and change 'Copy to Output' to 'Copy if Newer'.